# CSS Grid and transform: images overflow and overlap

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-grid

I am still a beginner, sorry if it's a silly question, I will try to keep it short and specific.

So, I wanted to create a zooming out effect in an image grid using CSS grid display and transform scale properties.

The result I got was off from the desired result, I'll post images of both after the code.

Here's the code I have used:

```css
.meals-gallery {
  background-color: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.meals-gallery img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
}

.meals-gallery img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

```html
<section class="meals-gallery">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
</section>
```

The images overlap while being at 70% opacity, so they look ugly, even though I have added overflow property to be hidden..

Here's the desired effect:

[image: Desired image effect]

And here's what I have achieved:

[image: The effect I get]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we'll need to wrap the `img` elements in a container, like a `div`, and use `overflow: hidden;` on the `div`. Then we can `transform: scale` the `img` elements on `div:hover`. I think this is the effect you're going for:

```css
.meals-gallery {
  background-color: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.meals-gallery > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.meals-gallery img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.meals-gallery div:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<section class="meals-gallery">
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt=""></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a ton. 
Just wondering, is there a neater way to do it? or I have to wrap each img element in a div?

Comment: In this case I think you'll need to wrap each element. Might also be possible by foregoing the `img` element and using a background image on the `div`, then transitioning the `background-size`. But nothing wrong with the way you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, yea, haven't thought about the background image solution.
Your input is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From this [blog](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example1/)

> `grid-gap` property to create a gap between my columns and rows of 10px.
>   This property is a shorthand for `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` so
>   you can set these values individually.

```css
.meals-gallery {
  background-color: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 35%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.meals-gallery img {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.meals-gallery img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

```html
<section class="meals-gallery">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
  <img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/600x500" alt="">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly that's not the effect I was looking for. 
Brett DeWoody's answer fixed it for me.